# Is there padding in a struct if it only contain chars?

Tags: c

```
struct dummy {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
};
```

Does this cause padding to be added in any situation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it would be unusual, the *implementation itself* decides whether or not that structure has padding, not the standard (C11 in this case).

The standard states, in `6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers` (only relevant paragraphs shown):

> 14/ Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an implementation defined manner appropriate to its type.
>
> 15/ Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.
>
> 17/ There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

So:

- the implementation defines alignment and therefore padding (from `14`).
- no padding at start but padding allowed between members (from `15`). There is nothing about only being allowed to pad for reasons of alignment, padding is allowed for *any* purpose, including "whims of the implementer". The only *requirement* is that the addresses increase with subsequent members, *not* that they increase by the smallest possible amount subject to their size and alignment.
- padding allowed after last member (from `17`), again for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your `struct` does *not* have any padding.

But, *if* you add something after `c` that needs *alignment* (e.g. `int`), you *will* get padding.

---

Here's a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct dummy {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
};

struct dummy2 {
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
    int foo;
};

int
main(void)
{

    printf("dummy=%zu\n",sizeof(struct dummy));
    printf("dummy2=%zu\n",sizeof(struct dummy2));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output:

```
dummy=3
dummy2=8
```

Without padding, `dummy` should be 3, which it *is*.

Without padding `dummy2` should be 7, but it is 8. So, the second `struct` adds a pad `char` to align `foo` to a 4 byte boundary.

Comment: This answer is actually wrong. While the vast majority of implementations may not need padding in this case, the standard leaves it totally up to the implementation how to align and therefore pad.

Comment: Re "*Your struct does* not *have any padding.*" This is by no means guaranteed.
/// Re "*But, if you add something after c that needs alignment (e.g. int), you* will *get padding.*", Not quite. You *may* get padding. Same if you add something before or between the existing fields. /// So this is answer is wrong when it says there isn't padding, and it's wrong when it says there is.

Comment: The padding depends on the implementation; I have coded for systems (ARM) where the ABI made struct size always be a multiple of 4